# Vector of Vectors c++

Tags: c++, vector

I have read the previous posts related to this topic and still have not solved my problem.  I have a vector of vectors and I am trying to place an item inside the second vector at an certain index. When I try to do this I seg fault. I have a feeling I'm missing something in regards to the declaration or initialization.

Header File

```
std::vector<std::vector<double>> vec;
```

Cpp File

```
vector<vector<double >>vec(num, vector<double>(num));
```

Insert into index

```
vec[index1][index2]=doubleValue;
```

Comment: I think we'll need to seen an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: most probably index1 >= num or index2 >= num.

Comment: What is `num` defined as? Are `index1` and `index2` both less than `num`?

Comment: When index1 =0 and index2=1 and doubleValue = 7.5 and num is 5

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you really want a global variable (which is generally a bad idea), then you need a declaration, not a definition, in the header:

```
extern std::vector<std::vector<double>> vec;
^^^^^^
```

You have (at least) two definitions, one of which is empty. You could end up with either in the final program, although I'm surprised you don't get a link error.

Be careful where you use this: it might not be initialised before other non-local variables, in which case you might get a segfault or other undefined behaviour if you try to access it from their initialisers. Finally, make sure that `index` and `index2` are less than whatever value of `num` you're using to initialise it.

Answer (score 2):

You have same variable `vec` declared in both header file and .cpp file

What happens, I believe, you're getting two independent copies of the `vec`, one in .cpp file and another in .cpp file where header is included to.

Solution would be in header file to make declaration `extern`, and include it in all relevant .cpp files

`extern std::vector<std::vector<double>> vec;` in the header

`std::vector<std::vector<double>> vec( ... );` in one .cpp file

all other .cpp files will see `extern` and refer to one and the only definition in .cpp

Answer (score 0):

When I used to run into segmentation faults related to vectors/matrixes, it's usually the vector/matrix that is too large, at least in my experience.

Use small tests, with 2 rows/columns at first, or try to decrement your `num` value so the vector/matrix can actually fit in your available memory.